# Convert tab file data to csv or excel format using java

Tags: java, excel, file, tabs, format

How to extract data from a tab file which has text data in form of rows and column and export it to csv or excel file format? Which language will be best to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the code you have
written so far and where you are stuck, then we can try to
help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it easily in PowerShell :

```
Import-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -Path D:\tabdelfile.txt | export-csv D:\commadelfile.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: But how do I put filter if I need only certain columns to get exported to commadelfile.csv ?

Comment: Import-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -Path D:\tabdel.txt | Select columname1, columname2 | export-csv commadel.csv -NoTypeInformation